# Javascript argument parameters and google maps

Tags: javascript, function, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, parameters

I'm introducing myself to Google Maps API, and to JavaScript as well.

I already have set my map on my website, and now I'm trying to dynamically set multiple markers on the same map.

For that, I wrote this function:

```
function teste(lat,long){
        alert (lat);
        alert (long);
        //var companyPos3 = new google.maps.LatLng(41.545308,-8.421782);
        var companyPos3 = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,long);
        var companyMarker3 = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: companyPos3,
              map: map,
             // icon: companyLogo,
              title:"Mar!!!" });
            //}      
        ...
    }
```

And my problem resides right here. I can't set the google.maps.LatLng with 'lat' and 'long' function parameters. However, the alert dialog messages pop up, showing the values that are from PHP.

I tried also to remove the alert function but the marker didn't show as well.

I'm not sure if it there is a Google Maps API trick, or JavaScript trick.

Oh, and if I set the values as the commented line, it works, but I don't want this solution :).

Comment: Weird. I wonder if you're getting garbage collected before companyMarker3.position gets evaluated. Just for grins, try making lat/long global, or doing something like position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat,long).

Comment: Where are you calling the `teste()` function? `lat`/`long` could also being treated as strings rather than numbers.

Comment: In response to boz, i'm calling on php this way:

echo '<script type="text/javascript"> teste(41.545308,-8.421782);</script>';

But i guess this is correct since i can get these values on the js function... :S

Comment: MrLeap, i tried with global variables but didn't worked...

Comment: @Sammy - In that case, try `var companyPos3 = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(lat),parseFloat(long));`

Comment: Boz, tried and failed, sorry :S

Comment: There might be a lot of other issues with the map. Maybe you could provide a jsFiddle[http://jsfiddle.net/]

Comment: Apparently, the OnLoad="" trigger/event didn't execute the placing of the map BEFORE the setting of my markers.

I resolved the bug calling each function, once at a time, in the middle of the body! ;)

Thank you all for your effort! :)

Kind regards,

Sam!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

long is the reserved word in JS. [Please check here](http://www.quackit.com/javascript/javascript_reserved_words.cfm). So, please try lng instead of long also for setting icon please see [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#Icons). Try something like

```
function teste(lat,lng){
    alert (lat);
    alert (lng);
    //var companyPos3 = new google.maps.LatLng(41.545308,-8.421782);
    var companyPos3 = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
    var companyMarker3 = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: companyPos3,
          map: map,
         // icon: companyLogo,
          title:"Mar!!!" });
        //}      
    ...
}
```

Comment: I create this **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y7X8x/1/)** for you please give it a try once

Comment: NicholasNet, You are going to take my accept on your solution! :).

Thank you for your Fiddle, it really helped. Your solution didn't fit as a glove on my project, but helped a lot!

Apparently, the OnLoad="" trigger/event didn't execute the placing of the map BEFORE the setting of my markers.

I resolved the bug with your function and calling each function, once at a time, in the middle of the body! ;)

Thank you all for your effort! :)

Kind regards,

Sam!